# Taking information from site which takes data from another site

Tags: php, curl

I have following situation. 3 sites `Site A`, `Site B` and `Site C`.

`Site B` pulling with curl array from `Site C` like this:

`Site B` file `data.php`:

```
function get_curl_content_tx($url) {
      $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
      $result = curl_exec($curl);
      curl_close($curl);
      return $result;
}
$url=get_curl_content_tx("http://Site_C_domain/ask/ID");

$total =json_decode($url,true);
```

Where `ID` is dynamical... Like this everything is fine. Now I'm trying from `Site A` following

```
function get_curl_content_from_site_b($url) {
      $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
      $result = curl_exec($curl);
      curl_close($curl);
      return $result;
}
$url=get_curl_content_tx("http://Site_B_domain/data.php");

$total =json_decode($url,true);

var_dump($total);
```

So the question:

1. The `ID` which `Site B` is pulling info about should come to Site B
   from Site A. How?

I'm also happy to see if there are other solutions here. Main part is Site A send ID to Site B and Site B pull from Site C return to Site B and Site B to Site A..

Comment: Do you think this should have been like $url=get_curl_content_tx("http://Site_B_domain/data.php?ID=12");

Comment: Yes, should be like this. The problem is what to do in `Site B`? How to get that ID and send it to `Site C` for the info? Currently `$url=get_curl_content_tx("Site_B_domain/data.php?ID=12");` return `NULL` which is normal because Site B doesn't know what to do with this ID?

Comment: hi, is this what you want site A sends id to site B, site B then sends this id to site C which then returns to B and then to A? Or Site A send id to site B, site B sends some req to get data from Site C.. Site B then process ID from site A and data from site B and then sends respose back to site A

Comment: This is what I need `site A sends id to site B, site B then sends this id to site C which then returns to B and then to A` Site B is just intermediary site.

Comment: Do you think this makes sense $url=get_curl_content_tx("http://Site_C_domain/ask/".$_GET["ID"]); in site B

Comment: I mean once Site B get the ID from Site A and send it to Site C will receive array from Site C.. Site A need to get full array..

Comment: @Raj, $_GET['ID'] is `NULL`..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135779/discussion-between-raj-and-jason-paddle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code..

> a.php //url a.php?id=123 ,accepts id as a parameter

```
<?php
function get_curl_content_from_site_b($url) {

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HEADER=> 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=> 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> 0
    ));
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);   

      curl_close($curl);
      return $resp;
}
$url=get_curl_content_from_site_b("http://localhost/so/b.php?id=".$_GET["id"]);

?>
```

> b.php

```
<?php
function get_curl_content_tx($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HEADER=> 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=> 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> 0
    ));
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);   

      curl_close($curl);
      return $resp;


}
$url=get_curl_content_tx("http://localhost/so/c.php?id=".$_GET["id"]);
?>
```

> c.php

```
<?php
    print_r(array($_GET["id"],23));exit;        
?>
```

c.php will get the id value that propagated through b and is expected to return an array after some processing

Answer (score 1):

**Site B:**

Set the additional response header

```
header('X-Site-C-ID: 10');
```

**Site A:**

Read the response header from Site B

```
$siteCId = null;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, function ($ch, $line) use (&$siteCId) {
    $headerName = 'X-Site-C-ID: ';
    if (strpos($line, $headerName) !== false) {
        $siteCId = trim($line, "$headerName\n");
    }
    return strlen($line);
});
$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($siteCId);
```

**=======UPDATE=======**

As I see that case:

You have `Site B` with URI `site.b/getDataFromSiteC`

The code that handles request path `getDataFromSiteC` looks like

```
function get_curl_content_tx($url) {
      $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
      $result = curl_exec($curl);
      curl_close($curl);
      return $result;
}

$id = 10;
$url = get_curl_content_tx("http://site.c/ask/$id");    
$total = json_decode($url, true);
// some actions with $total ...

// set the additional header
header("X-Site-C-ID: $id");
```

Now if you make request to `site.b/getDataFromSiteC` in the response headers will additional header `X-Site-C-ID: 10`

You have `Site A` with URI `site.a/getDataFromSiteB` with following code:

```
$siteCId = null;
$ch = curl_init('site.b/getDataFromSiteB');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, function ($ch, $line) use (&$siteCId) {
    $headerName = 'X-Site-C-ID: ';
    if (strpos($line, $headerName) !== false) {
        $siteCId = trim($line, "$headerName\n");
    }
    return strlen($line);
});
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($siteCId !== null) {
   // you get Site C ID through Site B
   echo $siteCId;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what is this and where to set it `header('X-Site-C-ID: 10');`? And in the `read the response header from Site B` this in my curl function?

Comment: 1) Set the header in the same place where you make a request to `http://Site_C_domain/ask/ID`, as I understand  is it `Site B`

Comment: Yes, is `site B` but what is this `X-Site-C-ID: 10` do I need to change this ?

Comment: 2) This is a additional option `curl_setopt` to you curl function `Site A`

Comment: Like this? `$url=get_curl_content_tx(header('https://example.com/ask/: '. $_GET['ID']));`

Comment: No, if `Site B` with function `get_curl_content_tx` is your site, in response add `header` function

Comment: Sorry it's unclear for me how, what and where to put.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's a bit more clear but still got `NULL`. @Raj, solution is working so far.

Answer (score 0):

From the formatting of the URLs my best guess is the data being returned is different. Cane we get examples of what each curl call is getting in return?

Comment: it's getting array with data for user ID. It's really not important now. Main problem is how to send ID from `Site A` to `Site B` and then `Site B` request data from `Site C` and return it to `Site A` thats the problem.